# Can a compiler generate useless assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I am trying to find the meaning of assembly code generated from a c program. Here is the program in C:

```
int* a = &argc;
int b = 8;
a = &b;
```

Here is the assembly code generated with explanations. There is one part that I do not understand:

Prologue of the main:

```
leal    4(%esp), %ecx
andl    $-16, %esp
pushl   -4(%ecx)
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
pushl   %ecx
subl    $36, %esp
```

Load the address of argc in %eax:

```
movl    %ecx, %eax
```

The part I do not get:

```
movl    4(%eax), %edx
movl    %edx, -28(%ebp)
```

Stack-Smashing Protector code (setup):

```
movl    %gs:20, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -12(%ebp)
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
```

Load values in a and b (see in main.c):

```
movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
movl    $8, -20(%ebp)
```

Modify the value of a (a = &b):

```
leal    -20(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
```

Stack-Smashing Protector code (verify the stack is ok):

```
movl    $0, %eax
movl    -12(%ebp), %edx
xorl    %gs:20, %edx
je  .L7
call    __stack_chk_fail
```

If the stack is Ok:

```
.L7:
    addl    $36, %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

So the part I do not uinderstand is modifying the value in -28(%ebp), an address never used. Does someone knows why is this part generated?

Comment: If you compile without optimizations (the default) then the compiler output will contain all the loads/stores to memory even if they aren't needed. Take your code and put it in a function that isn't `main`, and compile with optimizations on (`-O3`)

Comment: dont use main(), make your code under test some other function name.  the main() question has been asked and answered a zillion times...

Comment: You told the compiler to turn off its brain by not specifying an optimization flag and now you wonder that it generates strange code?

Comment: If I optimize with -O1, the only thing that remains in the main is mov $0, %eax and then  ret

Comment: @DJ_Joe And damn right so.  Use `volatile` if you want to force the compiler to emit useless code. Or write test cases that actually do some meaningful work the compiler cannot simply remove.

Comment: @old_timer I would normally agree, but since OP specifically use the variable `argc` it makes sense.

Comment: I guess I am reading the question a different way, peace...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good way to see what the compiler does. I assume you have a file called main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int* a = &argc;
    int b = 8;
    a = &b;
}
```

Compile with debug info to an object file:

```
$ gcc -c -g main.c
```

View the assembly:

```
$ objdump -S main.o

main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   7:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
    int* a = &argc;
   b:   48 8d 45 ec             lea    -0x14(%rbp),%rax
   f:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    int b = 8;
  13:   c7 45 f4 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,-0xc(%rbp)
    a = &b;
  1a:   48 8d 45 f4             lea    -0xc(%rbp),%rax
  1e:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  22:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  27:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  28:   c3                      retq
```

Then do the same with full optimization:

```
$ gcc -c -g -O3 main.c
```

And view the assembly again:

```
$ objdump -S main.o

main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int* a = &argc;
    int b = 8;
    a = &b;
}
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   c3                      retq
```

So the answer is yes. The compiler can produce instructions not needed. That's why you turn on optimizations. When they are turned off, the compiler does its job in a very generic way without thinking at all. For example, it reserves space for variables that are not used.

Comment: Ok thank you. What I found quite surprising is that the assembly part did not correspond to any part of the C source code. But it's true that since the program does nothing, every line of the assembly should be considered as useless

Comment: There is an art to crafting C functions to compile and disassemble to see what the compiler is doing.  low optimization levels the compiler saves everything to stack/memory and retrieves form there and then if you have dead code it may write something that it never reads that is expected but that is in part because your program might have done that.  writing test functions that are not dead code or optimized into something not interesting takes some practice.

Comment: @DJ_Joe: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output, especially the link to [Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4), it's exactly what @ old_time was talking about.

Comment: Sadly, the answer to the title question of OP is "yes" even in optimized code, with complex-enough source the compiler will eventually have to stop with optimization calculations, and emit what is reasonably pruned correct code doing what it should. To create **optimal** code would take way too much time, with any large source base of modern SW projects it would take probably either straight beyond lifetime of universe, or at least thousands of years. To get near-optimal solution is something completely different (NP vs P problems), and current compilers are very good at this.

Comment: @Ped7g It is even impossible to create optimal code. Mainly because we don't have a good definition of "optimal". It it smallest code? Fastest code? Smallest memory consumption? What does "fastest"? Fastest response time or throughput?